# Cisco 1000BaseT SFP modules in a 3750 overheating

Tags: cisco, gigabit-ethernet, cisco-catalyst, sfp

I have a 3750 responsible for switching in my DMZ.  Every once in a while one of the gigabit links will go down although ios and the server attached to it report the link is up (activity lights, etc).

My solution is to remove the 1000BaseT SFP module (which is almost too hot to handle) and let it cool off.  Once plugged back in, everything returns to normal for about a week or two.  The SFP isn't the issue, I've replaced it with several.

Does anyone have experience with SFP modules overheating?

EDIT: the switch CAN be moved.  Just not to another rack.

Comment: If you cant move anything, we can't do much. An electric fan ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  It can be moved.  Just not to another rack.  Currently it sits on a shelf towards the top of the rack.

Comment: Have you checked that the switch cooling fan or fans is/are working.

Comment: yes, they work.  The rest of the switch has a pretty consistent temperature.  The SFP modules are the only part that are hot.